# Type object 'X' has no attribute 'DoesNotExist' with django

Tags: python, django

I keep getting the `has no attribute DoesNotExist` error.

Any ideas why?

So far I tried:

```
    try:
        current_report = Report.objects.get(account_profile=current_profile)
    except Report.DoesNotExist:
        print("report doesn't exist")
        current_report=None
```

And my debug shows `type object 'Report' has no attribute 'DoesNotExist'`
at line current_report(etc):

I also tried:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
...
except Report.ObjectDoesNotExist:
```

and

```
try:
    Report.objects.get(account_profile=current_profile)
except Report.DoesNotExist:
    print("report doesn't exist")
    current_report=None
```

and

```
try:
    Report.objects.get(account_profile=current_profile)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    print("report doesn't exist")
    current_report=None
```

Why does type object 'X' have no attribute 'DoesNotExist'? I'm using django.

In my Models.py I have:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    account_profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    total_visitors = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    last_week_visitors = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    new_visitors_this_wk = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    new_visitors_last_wk = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    bounce_rate = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    last_week_bounce_rate = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    percent_new_referrals = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    last_week_new_referrals = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    this_week_pg_load_time = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    last_week_pg_load_time = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    week_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)

    #HTML table for browsers with avg session durations less than 10 seconds
    sessions_vs_browser = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    sessions_vs_country = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    sessions_vs_device = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    total_sessions = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    keywords = models.ManyToManyField(Keyword)
    referrals = models.ManyToManyField(Referral)
    pages_speeds = models.ManyToManyField(PageSpeed)
    bounces = models.ManyToManyField(BouncePage)
```

Comment: Are you sure Report is a model class here? Have you imported the right thing?

Comment: The error message is literally correct. `Report` doesn't have an attribute of that name (either by definition or by inheritance). It's not clear why you think it should have the attribute or why you're confused about the very correct error message.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Import the exception,

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
```

And catch it

```
try:
    Report.objects.get(account_profile=current_profile)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    print("report doesn't exist")
    current_report=None
```

Because ObjectDoesNotExist is a Django specific exception and you have to import it in order to catch it.

Also it is not a property of the model to do `Model.ObjectDoesNotExist`

Comment: Yes, I did import it, check after `I also tried (...)` Then I get the error: `AttributeError at /viewreport/
type object 'Report' has no attribute 'objects' `

Comment: Check your ModelManager, check if you imported Model correctly, check if you overridden your model.

Comment: No I'm new to Django so I haven't done any big customisation like changing the ModelManager

Comment: That's another question, anyway update question with the Model and your code

Comment: I've updated my models.py and I import it as `from app.models import Report`

Comment: Open up a shell `python manage.py shell` and try to import the Model then try to run `Report.objects.all()`, comment out the current code that's causing the error.

Comment: Solved. I was overriding my model. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I was also facing this kind of behavior, the problem was having the same View name and Model name.You only need to change the View name.

You can handle exception in both way using

1. Model specific exception.
2. django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist

---

```
try:
     Report.objects.get(account_profile=current_profile)
except Report.DoesNotExist:
     print("report doesn't exist")
     current_report=None
```

or

```
try:
     Report.objects.get(account_profile=current_profile)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
     print("report doesn't exist")
     current_report=None
```

**DoesNotExist**

exception Model.DoesNotExist

> This exception is raised by the ORM in a couple places, for example by            QuerySet.get()
>   when an object is not found for the given query parameters.
>   Django provides a DoesNotExist exception as an attribute of each model class to identify the class of object that could not be found
>   and to allow you to catch a particular model class with try/except.
>   The exception is a subclass of
>   django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when we create the function or class with the same name as the model.